# Animate divs on load and then rotate inside a parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, transition

I have making a simple skills block on my website. I have skillsWheel class on parent div and then I have an inner div with h2 with a class of Skills. skillsWheel also includes 8 more divs with a class of skill. I have skills div and all the skill div centred inside the skillsWheel with only skills div showing and skill divs hide behind the skills div. I want the skill divs to show with animation on page load to make a circle around the skills div and then start rotating clock or anti clock wise or both. Any idea what I have to do to accomplish this? So far I have done this much.

```css
.skillsWheel {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #d7d7d7;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

div {
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.skill{
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background: crimson;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -35px;
  margin-left: -35px;
  z-index: -5;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
          transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}


.skill:nth-child(2) {
  top: 15%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.skill:nth-child(3) {
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.skill:nth-child(4) {
  top: 70%;
  left: 25%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.skill:nth-child(5) {
  top: 85%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.skill:nth-child(6) {
  top: 70%;
  left: 75%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.skill:nth-child(7) {
  top: 45%;
  left: 85%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.skill:nth-child(8) {
  top: 25%;
  left: 75%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.skill:nth-child(9) {
  top: 45%;
  left: 15%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.skills-main {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #98bf21;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  
}

.skills-main h5 {
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="skillsWheel">
    <div class="skills-main">
      <h5> Skills </h5>
    </div>
    
    <div class="skill">HTML</div>
    <div class="skill">CSS</div>
    <div class="skill">JavaScript</div>
    <div class="skill">jQuery</div>
    <div class="skill">Sass</div>
    <div class="skill">BootStrap</div>
    <div class="skill">Git</div>
    <div class="skill">Photoshop</div>
    
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because I believe that I'll have to add javascript to add classes to individual divs upon page load.

Comment: Just tried by creating a css class show and adding it to the first skill div by enclosing in window.onload to see if it works but no luck. That's why I just cleared that part

Comment: Include what you have tried into your question?

Comment: the labels must rotate also?

Comment: Yes the whole skill div should rotate, all the skill divs but not the centresd div with label skills

Comment: Share your demo link. It will be easy for us to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a keyframe (ensure you use prefixes for cross compatibility)

```
@keyframes rotate{
from {
transform:rotate(0deg)
}
to{
transform:rotate(360deg)
}
}
```

create a div with class `skill_container` and add all `skill` container inside.

and add an animation rules to your container with `skill` class (prefix is also required)

```
 animation-name:rotate;
  animation-duration:1s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
```

Snippet below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".skill").css({
    width: "70px",
    height: "70px"
  })
})
```

```css
.skillsWheel {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #d7d7d7;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

div {
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.skill {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background: crimson;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -35px;
  margin-left: -35px;
  z-index: -5;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.skill:nth-child(2) {
  top: 15%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.skill:nth-child(3) {
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.skill:nth-child(4) {
  top: 70%;
  left: 25%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.skill:nth-child(5) {
  top: 85%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.skill:nth-child(6) {
  top: 70%;
  left: 75%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.skill_container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.skill:nth-child(7) {
  top: 45%;
  left: 85%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.skill:nth-child(8) {
  top: 25%;
  left: 75%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.skill:nth-child(9) {
  top: 45%;
  left: 15%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.skills-main {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #98bf21;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

.skills-main h5 {
  font-size: 22px;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div class="skillsWheel">
    <div class="skills-main">
      <h5> Skills </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="skill_container">
      <div></div>
      <div class="skill">HTML</div>
      <div class="skill">CSS</div>
      <div class="skill">JavaScript</div>
      <div class="skill">jQuery</div>
      <div class="skill">Sass</div>
      <div class="skill">BootStrap</div>
      <div class="skill">Git</div>
      <div class="skill">Photoshop</div>
    </div>


  </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I wanted the skill divs to revolve around the big round div. Like their position should be changing.